# How to get value of other json element in java 8

Tags: java, json, java-8

I have a JSON for string jsonArrayStr

```
[
  {
    "DebtorAccount": "1716429833",
    "CreditorAccount": "NL97RABO5372111783",
    "Amount": 2.6,
    "EndBalance": 1367.99,
    "TransactionTime": "27-Jun-2018 04:04 PM",
    "Label": "Rent"
  },
  {
    "DebtorAccount": "1792432233",
    "CreditorAccount": "NL27RABO4067005407",
    "Amount": 199.37,
    "EndBalance": 271.72,
    "TransactionTime": "07-Jul-2013 03:40 AM",
    "Label": "Internet"
  },
  {
    "DebtorAccount": "0417164298",
    "CreditorAccount": "NL97RABO5372111783",
    "Amount": 2.2,
    "EndBalance": 1367.99,
    "TransactionTime": "27-Jun-2018 04:04 PM",
    "Label": "Rent"
  }
]
```

I want to get a list of all the amounts having DebtorAccount = NL95RABO0417164298 and Label = Rent.

I tried below code to get all the values for the DebtorAccount = NL95RABO0417164298, however I am not able to fetch amount value.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayStr);
IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.length())
  .mapToObj(index -> ((JSONObject)jsonArray.get(index)).optString("DebtorAccount")).filter(p -> p.equals("NL95RABO0417164298"))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please help me, what am I missing?

Comment: 1) If you only want the amounts of some of the objects, you need a `filter(...)`. --- 2) If you want the *amount* value, you should probably extract that, rather than the *account number*.

Comment: I am getting DebtorAccount having value as NL95RABO0417164298 as arguments. Now I need to filter Amount values as a list. Please let me know, how to use filter to get Amount values.

Comment: Please do your own **research**, e.g. a web search for [`java how to use filter`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+how+to+use+filter) would do the trick.

Comment: I know how to use filters, however I am not able to get values depending upon other elements in the json arrays

Comment: Those look like valid bank account numbers, are you sure you want them published here?

Comment: *"I know how to use filters"* Then why not show us, e.g. `filter(index -> ((JSONObject)jsonArray.get(index)).optString("DebtorAccount").equals(debtorAccount))`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this can be achieved using [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-).

The below code snippet filters out all the `JSONObject`(s) having DebtorAccount = NL95RABO0417164298 and Label = Rent, and stores the result in `filteredJSONArray`.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayStr);
JSONArray filteredJSONArray = new JSONArray();

IntStream
        .range(0, jsonArray.length())
        .filter(index -> jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).get("DebtorAccount").equals("NL95RABO0417164298") && jsonArray.getJSONObject(index).get("Label").equals("Rent"))
        .forEach(index -> filteredJSONArray.put(jsonArray.get(index)));

System.out.println(filteredJSONArray.toString());
```